# Trouble implementing chained variables in Makefile

Tags: bash, variables, makefile

I'm looking to use the previous variable to look up the next variable (these should all be set as envvars) I have this working in a smaller extent with just profile, but when i try chaining variables together they fall flat...

Expected output is that `make build` has `TF_VARS_*` set as envvars and that they are able to be used as regular variables for the next variable input. I assume that there should be an export of `TF_VAR_aws_profile` `TF_VAR_aws_vpc` and `TF_VAR_aws_net` into global scope, this seemed to work fine for when I was JUST using `TF_VAR_aws_profile` and was able to confirm with `echo $TF_VAR_aws_profile`

```
export TF_VAR_aws_profile TF_VAR_aws_vpc TF_VAR_aws_net

# An implicit guard target, used by other targets to ensure
# that environment variables are set before beginning tasks
assert-%:
    @ if [ "${${*}}" = "" ] ; then               \
        echo "Environment variable $* not set" ; \
        exit 1 ;                                 \
    fi

vault:
    ## This is the problem section here....
    @ read -p "Enter AWS Profile Name: " profile ; \
    vpc=$(shell aws --profile "$${profile}" --region us-west-2 ec2 describe-vpcs |jq -r '.[] | first | .VpcId') ; \
    net=$(shell aws --profile "$${profile}" --region us-west-2 ec2 describe-subnets --filters "Name=vpc-id,Values=$${vpc}" |jq -r '.[] | first | .SubnetId') ; \
    TF_VAR_aws_profile=$$profile TF_VAR_aws_vpc=$$vpc TF_VAR_aws_net=$$net make build && \
    TF_VAR_aws_profile=$$profile make keypair && \
    TF_VAR_aws_profile=$$profile make plan    && \
    TF_VAR_aws_profile=$$profile make apply

build: require-packer
    aws-vault exec $(TF_VAR_aws_profile) --assume-role-ttl=60m -- \
    "/usr/local/bin/packer" "build"                               \
      "-var" "builder_subnet_id=$(TF_VAR_aws_net)"             \
      "-var" "builder_vpc_id=$(TF_VAR_aws_vpc)"                   \
    "packer/vault.json"

require-packer: assert-TF_VAR_aws_vpc assert-TF_VAR_aws_net
    @ echo "[info] VPC:  $(TF_VAR_aws_vpc)" ## Not set
    @ echo "[info] NET:  $(TF_VAR_aws_net)" ## Not set
    packer --version &> /dev/null
```

**UPDATE**

Looks like it might be something to do with line termination on the vault expression, added `; \` to continue the lines

Comment: You have an incorrect construct in checking for the argument concatenated list, `"${${*}}"` should have been just `$*`

Comment: @Inian interesting, because that seemed to work fine in another `Makefile` I wrote, source: https://github.com/ehime/terraform-multiregion-openvpn/blob/master/Makefile which this one is based on.

Comment: That cannot have worked ever in a shell running `sh` or `bash`

Comment: I believe its because `$$*` actually evaluates to `$*` due to escapism in Makefiles. Keep in mind this is a Makefile and not pure Bash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it, it was a combination of TWO things, one running as `$(shell \$CMD)` does not evaluate the inner expression variables, I needed to revert to `ticks` instead to evaluate variables (keep in mind, variables STILL need `$$` in order to evaluate inside of Makefiles) as well as the lines needed to be continued, so terminating only with `;` is not effective, we need to use `; \`.

Please note that I updated my variable names from above, they are now `$$subnet` and `$$prvnet` because I'm a spacing nazi...

```
export TF_VAR_aws_profile TF_VAR_aws_prvnet TF_VAR_aws_subnet


# An implicit guard target, used by other targets to ensure
# that environment variables are set before beginning tasks
assert-%:
    @ if [ "${${*}}" = "" ] ; then             \
        echo "Environment variable $* not set" ; \
        exit 1 ;                                 \
    fi

vault:
    @ read -p "Enter AWS Profile Name: " profile ;  \
    prvnet=`aws --profile "$${profile}" --region us-west-2 ec2 describe-vpcs |jq -r '.[] | first | .VpcId'` ;                                                 \
    subnet=`aws --profile "$${profile}" --region us-west-2 ec2 describe-subnets --filters "Name=vpc-id,Values=$${prvnet}" |jq -r '.[] | first | .SubnetId'` ;   \
    TF_VAR_aws_profile=$$profile TF_VAR_aws_prvnet=$$prvnet TF_VAR_aws_subnet=$$subnet make build &&                                                          \
    TF_VAR_aws_profile=$$profile make keypair &&    \
    TF_VAR_aws_profile=$$profile make plan    &&    \
    TF_VAR_aws_profile=$$profile make apply

build: require-packer
    aws-vault exec $(TF_VAR_aws_profile) --assume-role-ttl=60m -- \
    "/usr/local/bin/packer" "build"                               \
      "-var" "builder_subnet_id=$(TF_VAR_aws_net)"             \
      "-var" "builder_vpc_id=$(TF_VAR_aws_vpc)"                   \
    "packer/vault.json"

require-packer: assert-TF_VAR_aws_prvnet assert-TF_VAR_aws_subnet
    @ echo "[info] VPC:  $(TF_VAR_aws_prvnet)" ;
    @ echo "[info] NET:  $(TF_VAR_aws_subnet)" ;
    packer --version &> /dev/null
```